# Resources Plugin -- How To include all contents in a directory?

Tags: grails, resources

I have a grails app that contains a whole mess of individual javascript files in a series of nested directories.  I want to manage them via the resources plugin, but don't want to have to explicitly register each one.

**Web Dir Structure**

```
webapp
  app
    controller
      controller1.js
      controller2.js
      ...
    model
      model1.js
      ...
    view
      view1.js
```

what would be great is to just declare in my `AppResources.groovy` file:

`resource url: 'app/**/*.js'`

but that doesn't work -- throws a null pointer.  I've tried:

`resource url: 'app/**'` but with no luck

I've thought that i would put some code in the config file that would recurse through the directory structure, but that doesn't seem to be working.  Here's what I've tried:

```
def iterClos = {
        it.eachDir( iterClos );
        it.eachFile {
            resource url: ${it.canonicalPath};

        }

    }

    iterClos( new File("$grails.app.context/app") )
```

Unfortunately that failed as well.

Does anyone have any ideas how I could achieve this?

Comment: There's a feature request for the Grails Resource Plugin to do this: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPRESOURCES-90
Just relaying here so if others don't want to rely on looping in the config they could vote on the JIRA as a potential alternative.

Comment: @virtualandy, I've added my comments to the jira feature request.  Folks seem to be missing out on the fact that it's a pain in the neck to manually enter each javascript file in a directory to the resources config.  Others, please vote for this feature in jira, yah?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

problem solved.

As it turns out, the idea of running code to recuse through my javascript directories works.  I just had the code incorrect.  Here is the code that dynamically loads my javascript files:

--AppResources.groovy

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder as SCH

modules = {
    core {
        resource url: '/resources/css/app.css', disposition: 'head'
        resource url: '/resources/css/myapp.css', disposition: 'head'
        resource url: '/extjs/ext-all-debug.js', dispostion: 'head'

        getFilesForPath('/app').each {
          resource url: it
        }
    }
}

def getFilesForPath(path) {

    def webFileCachePaths = []

    def servletContext = SCH.getServletContext()

    //context isn't present when testing in integration mode. -jg
    if(!servletContext) return webFileCachePaths

    def realPath = servletContext.getRealPath('/')

    def appDir = new File("$realPath/$path")

    appDir.eachFileRecurse {File file ->
        if (file.isDirectory() || file.isHidden()) return
        webFileCachePaths << file.path.replace(realPath, '')
    }

    webFileCachePaths
}
```

The above will cause the Resource plugin to track my javascript files.  Here's what the html looks like when Resources is in debug mode:

```
<script src="/myapp/extjs/ext-all-debug.js?_debugResources=y&n=1336614540164" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/myapp/app/controller/LogController.js?_debugResources=y&n=1336614540164" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/myapp/app/controller/LoginController.js?_debugResources=y&n=1336614540164" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/myapp/app/controller/ProfileController.js?_debugResources=y&n=1336614540164" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

...

Being new to Grails, it is a very welcome fact that one can put executable code within a config file!

Comment: I was just thinking about writing my own plugin to be able to do this because I could not find any info regarding it. Thanks!