# Make a whole folder visible with ApplicationResources

Tags: grails

in my grails application I would like to make all files in a specific folder in my `web-app` directory to be public so I can use them whenever I want. Is this possible when messing around with `ApplicationResources.groovy` config or is there any other smart way to make them public without calling them directly?

I imagine something like this: `resource url:'images/flags/*'`

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible and probably for good reason.

Comment: so if you just want to make a lot of files public, what is the best way to go then? :/

Comment: What do you mean by 'public'?  Accessible by the code or accessible by a user using your web site like a file system?

Comment: By a user using my website like a filesystem, well both actually. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the Resources plugin does not have this feature, see [Resources Plugin -- How To include all contents in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520693/resources-plugin-how-to-include-all-contents-in-a-directory).

The linked post does, however, include a solution.