# How do I specify wildcard resource patterns in Grails Resources Plugin?

Tags: javascript, grails, resources, bundle

The Grails resources plugin lets you define modules, and bundle a bunch of files into a single module.

Say I want a module to scoop up all the files in my /js/models folder and put them in a single module bundle called model

How would I specify that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resources Plugin -- How To include all contents in a directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520693/resources-plugin-how-to-include-all-contents-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon the same thing...

There is an accepted answer on SO: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520693/resources-plugin-how-to-include-all-contents-in-a-directory)

And a feature request for the resources-plugin with some good thoughts: [Link](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPRESOURCES-90)