# Grails web-app image directory is not working properly in war

Tags: tomcat, grails, debian, grails-2.0

I am working with Grails 2.4.2. I am saving images to a directory named gameImage under web-app folder. It's working perfectly in development mode. But when I run the war on localhost in the xampp server then in the view image is not showing but saving in the directory. Here are my attempts below ::

In my config file >>>

```
gameImage.location = "web-app/apps/gameImage/"
```

In my controller where saving image >>>

```
String fileName = grailsApplication.config.gameImage.location.toString() + distGameInstance.packageName + '_' + newGameImage.getOriginalFilename()
new File( grailsApplication.config.gameImage.location.toString() ).mkdirs()
newGameImage.transferTo( new File( fileName) )
```

In my view where I want to show the image >>>

```
<g:each in="${distributedGameListInstance}" status="i" var="androidDistGameInstance">
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb" >
      <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
          <g:img uri="${resource(dir: "apps/gameImage", file: "${androidDistGameInstance.imageName}")}" style="height: 120px;width: 120px;" />
      </a>
   </div>
</g:each>
```

Comment: and you have added apps folder to the rule as well grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*']

Comment: @vahid thanks for your reply but don't get it. Can you explain a little bit more please

Comment: add this line in config file but no result

Comment: and it included your apps folder too ? grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*', '/apps/*'] also take a look here try debugging it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741877/resource-not-found-error-and-what-about-resources-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to config about folder in config.groovy. just follow the below code. at least worked for me :::

```
    def gameImage = request.getFile('appImage')
String imagePath = "${request.getRealPath('/')}/apps/gameImage/"
new File( imagePath ).mkdirs()
gameImage.transferTo( new File( imagePath + File.separatorChar + gameImageName) )
```