# Can't load CSS style sheet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new in **HTML** and I'm trying to use **bootstrap** in my project.

The problem is that I can't load **bootstrap.min.css** and none of the classes work. I did some searching and tried some ways but they didn't work for me

Here is my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
%{--<!doctype html>--}%
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv = "X-UA-Compatible" content = "IE = edge">
  <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
  %{--<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">--}%
  
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="E:\TekDays\web-app\bootstrap-3.3.7-dist\css\bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
 <title>TekDays - The Community is the Conference!</title>

 </head>
  <body>
   <div class="container">
 <table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>FirstName</th>
    <th>FirstName</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
     <tr>
   <td>Mammad</td>
   <td>mammadii</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Akbar</td>
       <td>Akbarii</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

1. Using absolute path results in an error(use f12): Not allowed to load local resource: file:///E:/TekDays/web-app/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

I read somewhere that it's only chrome's error and Edge or IE browsers don't have this problem, they don't but the results are the same, css classes are not applied.

2. I put the **bootstrap.min.css** under the same directory as my html page is and used `<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">` instead of what is used in the code.

but this time I got error 404: not found 
This seems to be my problem with the path I've given...but I don't know what to do

Any idea what's wrong with it?

Comment: check your console to know if its throwing 404 error ?

Comment: Also could you post your folder structure ?

Comment: Check the extension of the `css` file. Maybe it is `bootstrap.min.css.txt`, and known file extensions are hidden in File Explorer

Comment: @Shahil GET http://localhost:8080/TekDays/bootstrap.min.css
its in the console

Comment: @MarkPerera I checked it. its 'bootstrap.min.css'

Comment: Try putting bootstrap.min.css to the root folder and add    

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">

Comment: If you are using rails, Run asset pre compile that should work in rails

Comment: The html file is also in the `TekDays` directory, right

Comment: change '\' to '/' in the path.

Comment: @Shahil I'm using grails 
but I tried 2 other ways and none of them seem to work

Comment: this might be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741877/resource-not-found-error-and-what-about-resources-plugin

Comment: @MarkPerera Its in E:\TekDays\grails-app\views and I copied bootstrap.min.css there and used  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"> but it doesnt work

Comment: Try copying both of them to a directory outside your project and check if it works

Comment: @Shahil http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741877/resource-not-found-error-and-what-about-resources-plugin 
thanks a lot it worked !!! :-)

Comment: Finally! :) Good that you were able to crack it.

Comment: You can accept the answer if that helped you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slash used here

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="E:\TekDays\web-app\bootstrap-3.3.7-dist\css\bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
```

would cause user browser to access the file from his filesystem.

Change the path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="E:/TekDays/web-app/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
```

**UPDATED ANSWER :**
[Resource not found Error and what about resources plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741877/resource-not-found-error-and-what-about-resources-plugin)

Comment: Error Not allowed to load local resource: file:///E:/TekDays/web-app/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv = "X-UA-Compatible" content = "IE = edge">
  <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <title>TekDays - The Community is the Conference!</title>

 </head>
  <body>
   <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>FirstName</th>
       <th>FirstName</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tr>
      <td>Mammad</td>
      <td>mammadii</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Akbar</td>
       <td>Akbarii</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: It workes but im intrested to load it from local sources 
But thanks for your help

Comment: open given link in your browser & save  it from your browser to your folder where are your index.html file & call it like: <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">

Answer (score -1):

its work check your css path

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv = "X-UA-Compatible" content = "IE = edge">
  <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  
 
 <title>TekDays - The Community is the Conference!</title>

 </head>
  <body>
   <div class="container">
 <table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>FirstName</th>
    <th>FirstName</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
     <tr>
   <td>Mammad</td>
   <td>mammadii</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Akbar</td>
       <td>Akbarii</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking why his code is not working

Comment: It workes thanks 
But do you know what was my problem with paths?

Comment: Try adding an additional slash in path this '\' may have problem use like E://TekDays//web-app//bootstrap-3.3.7-dist//css//bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Again the same error : Not allowed to load local resource: file:///E://TekDays//web-app//bootstrap-3.3.7-dist//css//bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score -1):

href replace with src

```
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">

<link *src*="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

Comment: No. The `<link>` element doesn't have a `src` attribute.